# How to use jquery from parent inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a file, let us call it parent-win.html, served by domain example.com. This file has jquery included in it. An iframe, lets call it iframe-win.html, is embedded in this page. iframe-win.html has a form element with id `form-elem` and value `Hello World!`. Now I do following inside iframe.

```
var jQuery = parent.jQuery;
console.log(jQuery('#form-elem').val());
```

According to my limited knowledge of JS I should see `Hello World!` on console but instead I see undefined. Now, my question is do I need to load jquery again in an iframe or can I utilise jquery object already loaded in parent window?

Do note that this is not as usual access iframe/parent content from parent/iframe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access jQuery library from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481613/access-jquery-library-from-iframe)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this in the iframe:

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
    var iframeBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, iframeBody); };
    var $ = jQuery;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I just now asked a colleague if I need to pass iframe as a context to jQuery. Thanks Moin!

Comment: This answer doesn't consider all the other argument types the jQuery function can take besides a string selector.

Comment: I found using document better than using iframebody: return parent.jQuery(selector, document)

Comment: This is not work on fancybox. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:55783" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Will this work in a pop out window? I've been trying something like: var jQuery = function (selector) { return window.opener.jQuery(selector, iframeBody); };

Answer (score 8):

Here is a better solution based on the Moin's answer:

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
    window.jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, document); };
    jQuery = parent.$.extend(jQuery, parent.$);
    window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

So we can use $'s functions like $.get, $.extends, etc.

Comment: and also works in `head` while Moin's answer must be put inside `body`

Comment: One-liner, quick & dirty: `window.$=window.jQuery=parent.jQuery.extend(function(s){return parent.jQuery(s,document)},parent.jQuery);`

Comment: The accepted solution did not work for me. This one did. Thanks Andrey!

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery inside the `iframe`.

EDIT: Okay, if the frame is not on the same domain, then you do *not* have to reload jQuery. See [Access jQuery library from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481613/access-jquery-library-from-iframe)

Comment: That I know. But if you console.log jQuery in the example given above it does show jQuery object. Moreover I can access an object from parent using parent.object() then why not jQuery?

Comment: Thom Smith, read the answer you linked to again, cos if the iframe is on different domain, you DO have to load jQuery inside it.

Comment: The answer linked to doesn't work, see its comments for details.