# Out of memory error in IE(any) and Firefox when trying to include jQuery from parent document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am dynamically loading iframes into a div. Those iframes need jQuery for their functionality. To avoid including jQuery into every single iframe I simply referenced jQuery in the iframe generator(the same code will be in the head of every iframe loaded) like so:

```
var jQuery = window.parent.$;  // The parent is the document that will house the iframes
var $ = jQuery;
```

This works just fine in Chrome and a substantial performance boost comes with loading jQuery only once. However both Firefox and IE start leaking memory like mad(both peak around 1gb of memory used) before throwing an out of memory error and dropping the script.

EDIT: jQuery 1.7 and jQueryUI 1.10.3(however jqUi is not used when loading the iframes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jquery from parent inside an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950034/how-to-use-jquery-from-parent-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: I have looked through those and several others. The idea works in Chrome, but none of them mention anything about FF and IE getting an out of memory error.

Comment: Note how jquery is initialized in the answer above. I think this caused these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that jQuery keeps a *context* which represents the scope in which to seek for elements when selecting. The default context is the `window.document` of the page that included jQuery.

When referencing a parent frame's jQuery global, the context will still remain the parent's `window.document`, which implies that all selections you do will happen in the parent frame, which is almost never the desired effect.

This can, depending on the case (i.e. protocol, domain and port of the two frames), lead to weird behavior because of [`SOP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions.

Your best bet is to dynamically insert the `<script>` tag referencing the same jQuery resource as the parent in the child frame. The browser will most likely have the file in cache.

By the way, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950158/532430) linked by [@undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined) as a comment to your question is a terrible idea since it will only allow for string selectors to work correctly but doesn't consider all the other argument types the jQuery function can take (e.g. a function to be bound to document onload).