# How to use same javascript/jquery for iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have written my own js/jquery code for some of the content on my website. now same content is inside iframe but js/jquery only applied for content without iframe.

any way i can re use same code for both contents ?

example i want this to work for both

```
$( ".myclass-price-info" ).appendTo( $( ".myclass-single" ) );
```

**Edit:**
example: i have this on my page as normal html

```
<div class="test"> This is test div </div>
```

Then i have same div inside iframe like below

```
<iframe src="">
   <html>
     <body>
     <div class="test"> This is test div </div>
     </body>
   </html>
</iframe>
```

this is only one div as an example i have full page with same example.

now i already wrote js/jquery to target my .test class and perform some js/jquery action. the js/jquery is working for normal html but not for iframe div. e.g i changed background of div its changed for normal html but not for div inside iframe.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with more detail about exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl edited my question

Comment: An iframe has it's own window. So you have to treat it like 2 completely different pages. Be more specific. Are you trying to have a duplicate inside the iframe?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not cross domain:

```
$('#iframeid').contents().find('.myclass-single').append('.myclass-price-info');
```

Comment: its same domain.

Comment: also means i have to change all my js code ? and redo for iframe ?

Comment: Should say *"if it's **not** cross domain"*

Comment: you don't have to put jquery inside the iframe, but just on the parent. But is not a problem if jquery is also there.

Comment: my real question is i have to edit my existing js code to target iframe content divs ? i have about 500 lines of code and do i have to re do this to target i frame divs ?

Comment: You can not access a cross domain iframe from parent page due to same origin policy is my point

Comment: Yes @DanishJamshed because for iframe you have to use *.contents().*

Comment: what if i insert all js code inside body of iframe ? will that work without contents() ?

Comment: Of course it will, but that you have to put jquery on all the frames.. or try to manage with something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950034